# Immediate window cannot find class in namespace

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, immediate-window

I have a method which is located like this in my code

```
namespace DMR
{
    public static class MyClass
    {
        public static void MyMethod()
        {
            // Do stuff here
            // (...)
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried calling it from the Immediate Window with the following command:

```
DMR.MyClass.MyMethod();
```

Which returns a namespace error:

> **The type or namespace name 'MyClass' does not exist in the namespace 'ProjectName.DMR'**

I have also tried adding the project name in front of the namespace in the call, but that doesn't change anything. I should perhaps note that the namespace is different from the folder name, since the folder name was changed after creation (without changing the namespace), I do not know, if this has any effect.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This will help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4664/should-the-folders-in-a-solution-match-the-namespace?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 0):

I decided to change the namespace to match the folder name. This made it work. I still don't know why the folder name of the file and the namespace has to be the same, so if anyone has an explanation for that, it would be nice.